# pandas, combine two rows to one, only for specific values, with an updated value

Tags: python, pandas

Current dataframe is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', delimiter=',')

print(df)
idx   uniqueID      String 

0        1           'hello'
1        1           'goodbye'
2        1           'yo'
4        2           'hello'
5        2           'sup'
6        3           'howdy'
7        3           'hello'
8        3           'goodbye'
```

Expected Output:

```
idx   uniqueID      String 

0        1           'greeting'
2        1           'yo'
4        2           'hello'
5        2           'sup'
6        3           'howdy'
7        3           'greeting'
```

*Effectively, if there is a consecutive pattern of 'hello' then 'goodbye' within the same uniqueID, they get merged to a single row and become a different string (which in this case I allocated to be 'greeting').*

Question: **How do I combine two rows to one, only for specific values, with an updated value I want?**

I'm thinking use of .loc would be ideal here, but unsure how to go about it. Thank you!

Comment: good approach, though the requirement is to have these two occurring consecutively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case do

```
idx = df.groupby('uniqueID')['String'].apply(lambda x : x.shift().eq('hello')&x.eq('goodbye'))
out = df.drop(idx.index[idx],axis=0)
out.loc[idx.index[idx]-1,'String'] = 'greeting'
out
Out[79]: 
   idx  uniqueID    String
0    0         1  greeting
2    2         1        yo
3    4         2     hello
4    5         2       sup
5    6         3     howdy
6    7         3  greeting
```

Comment: If I wanted to combine 3 rows instead of two (lets say hello goodbye hi), would I just add x.shift(-1).eq('hi'), with the 2 other params the same, and the index[idx]-2,'String'] change? Or is that a bigger change than I'm imagining.

Comment: @Ev0 adding one more condition , then drop two set of idx with -1

Answer (score 1):

here is one more way do it,

```
#using mask check if the consecutive values are hello and goodbye, and change the first value to greetings
df['String']=df['String'].mask(df['uniqueID'].eq(df['uniqueID'].shift(-1)) &
                               df['String'].str[1:-1].eq('hello') & 
                               df['String'].shift(-1).str[1:-1].eq('goodbye'),'greetings')
df


# identify the row above the greetings and drop it
df.drop(df.loc[df['String'].shift().eq('greetings') ].index)
```

```
    idx     uniqueID    String
0   0   1   greetings
2   2   1   'yo'
3   4   2   'hello'
4   5   2   'sup'
5   6   3   'howdy'
6   7   3   greetings
```